# Big O complexity on dependent nested loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Can I get some help in understanding how to solve this tutorial question! I still do not understand my professors explanation. I am unsure of how to count the big 0 for the third/most inner loop. She explains that the answer for this algorithm is O(n^2) and that the 2nd and third loop has to be seen as one loop with the big 0 of O(n). Can someone please explain to me the big O notation for the 2nd / third loop in basic layman terms
Assuming n = 2^m

```
for ( int i = n; i > 0; i --) {     
  for (int j =1; j < n; j *= 2){
        for (int k =0; k < j; k++){
        }
  }
 }
```

As far as I understand, the first loop has a big O notation of O(n)
Second loop = log(n)
Third loop = log (n) (since the number of times it will be looped has been reduced by logn) * 2^(2^m-1)( to represent the increase in j? )

Comment: outermost loop runs `n` times. loop with `j` as looping variable runs `log(n)` times. Inner most loop will run `m` times. And as stated, `n = 2^m, log(n) = m`. Hence overall complexity will be `O(2^m * m^2)`

Comment: @taurus05 how do u get that the inner loop will run m times?

Comment: You have to determine the maximum number of times each loop runs & then multiply the running times of all three to determine the overall complexity.

Comment: can i get more help please. i still do not understand

Answer (score 1):

lets add print statement to the innermost loop.

```
for (int j =1; j < n; j *= 2){
        for (int k =0; k < j; k++){
            print(1)
        }
}
```

output for

`j = 1`, `1 1`

`j = 2`, `1 1 1`

`j = 4`, `1 1 1 1 1`

...

`j = n`, `1 1 1 1 1 ...` `n+1` times.

The question boils down to how many `1`s will this print.

That number is

`(2^0 + 1) + (2^1 + 1) + (2^2 + 1) + ... + (n + 1)`

= `(2^0 + 1) + (2^1 + 1) + (2^2 + 1) + ... + (n + 1)`

= `log n + (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n)`

= `O(log n + n)`

= `O(n)`.

---

assuming you know why `(1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n) = O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = n; i > 0; i --) {   // This runs n times  
  for (int j =1; j < n; j *= 2){  // This runs atmost log(n) times, i.e m times.
        for (int k =0; k < j; k++){  // This will run atmost m times, when the value of j is m.
        }
  }
 }
```

Hence, the overall complexity will be the product of all three, as mentioned in the comments under the question.
Upper bound can be loose or tight.
You can say that it is `loosely bound under O(n^2)` or `tightly bound under O(n * m^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

`O`-notation is an upperbound. You can say it has O(n^2). For least upperbound, I believe it should be `O(n*log(n)*log(n))` which belongs to `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because of the logarithm. If you have log(16) raised to the power 2 is 16. So log(n) raised to the power of 2 is n. That is why your teacher says to view the second and third loop as O(n) together.

If the max iterations for the second loop are O(log(n)) then the second and third loops will be: O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + log(n)) = O(log(n)(log(n) + 1)/2) = O((log(n)^2 + log(n))/2) = O(n)